How can I use bash auto-completion to list the contents of a directory literally named "="?
For example, using Tab to auto-complete, with a relative path:

user:~$ ls -la /foo
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  60 Nov  9 22:31  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 260 Nov  9 22:31  ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 100 Nov  9 22:31 '='
user:~$ cd /foo
user:/foo$ ls =Tab
user:/foo$ ls =\=/

It inserts a spurious = with the initial Tab keypress, which is an invalid path and will never list any results:

ls: cannot access '==/': No such file or directory

(Unless, of course, someone was brazen enough to name a directory ==. Ridiculous, IMO.)
Trying with an absolute path might be more revealing to someone that understands this voodoo:

user:/foo$ ls /foo/=Tab
user:/foo$ ls /foo/=/foo/\=/

So it's not just the = it is trying to escape on a word break char, but it is repeating the entire current word.
Is this a bug? Maybe a pathological effect of some intended behavior? What's the best way to work around it assuming I can't change the directory name?
Edit
The above behavior is using GNU bash 5.2.32 and bash_completion 2.14.0.

Can't reproduce with the same version of bash but I don't have bash_completion installed.

@oguzismail  bash_completion is the issue

Completion issues
This is due to a bug in your installed completion system (not a bash bug).
1st way: just bash
You could try to run a sub bash without rcfile pre execution, by:

 $ bash --norc
 $ ls =/Tab

Will work, but avoiding rc file is no a real solution.
(Note: you could uninstall bash_completion package).
2nd escape way:
You could escape your equal before hitting key Tab:

 $ ls \=/Tab

Will work and won't conflict at execution.
3nd variable way:
You could workaround this bug by storing your equal sign into a variable:

 $ equal='='
 $ ls $equal/Tab

Will work too.

The only solutions I can come up with are to use the path indirectly via symlink or a variable, e.g.:

user:/foo$ ln -s = eq
user:/foo$ ls eq/Tab

user:/foo$ p='/foo/='
user:/foo$ ls $p/Tab

Or to remove = from COMP_WORDBREAKS ("'><=;|&(:, by default):

user:/foo$ $ export COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//=}
user:/foo$ ls =/Tab

